# How to read badly formatted input data in C++?

Tags: c++, stl, containers

I am learning C++ and am stuck on an exercise. How do you read data that is not formatted correctly? For example, I am given a file where I need to read data that looks like this:

```
1   z 2
1   xy 2
3   A 8000  E 1777  E 2001
```

The first, second, and third lines make up a "module". There is a lot of data for many modules that will be input through the keyboard. My program has to accept all of the user's input (until the user decides to type "q" to quit) and then read that input and manipulate the data. Ideally, the input will be formatted correctly like the example above, but sometimes the data will have extra whitespace, tabs, carriage returns, or start with data from the previous module, like this:

```
2   R 5001  E 4777 1   z 2     1   xy 2
3   A 8000  E 1777
E 2001
```

What is the best way to read and manipulate input data with bad formatting? In this case I want to be able to extract `1 z 2`, `1 xy 2`, and `3 A 8000 E 1777 E 2001` and store it in an array or some kind of STL container and be able to do something with this information later (like add, subtract, or multiply a number based on whether there is an "A", "S", or "M" in front of that number).

My program has to be able to recognize that z and xy are variables and that z = 2 and xy = 2.

Comment: May be should try using Regular Expression.. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/

Answer (score 2):

You would get better answers if you described the logical purpose of parts of your input better.  I'm going to *guess* that each module starts with a count of how many variable name/numeric-value pairs will follow, which allows a more structured approach to reading and storing the values.  I populate a vector (array) of maps (binary trees) from variable name to value, which is likely to be convenient for later lookups and processing.

```
std::vector<std::map<std::string, int>>> vars;
int vars_in_module;
while (cin >> vars_in_module)
{
    vars.emplace_back();  // add an empty module to vector
    std::string identifier;
    int value;
    for (int i = 1; i <= vars_in_module; ++i)
        if (cin >> identifier >> value)
            vars.back()[identifier] = value;  // add var to module
        else
        {
            std::cerr << "error parsing variable identifier & value\n";
            exit(1);
        }
}
```

The `map` does re-sort lexicographically (using ASCII order of the left-most character, then - if that's equal - the one to the right etc.) rather than preserve the order in which they were typed, which may or may not matter depending on the use to which you put the variables.  `map`s are fast to search for a particular identifier later, but you could use a `vector` if you cared about the input order.

Comment: I think this is the way to go. This makes a lot of sense and does seem to answer the pretty confusing question :). Good job!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::cin >>` to avoid white-space

```
std::string input = "";
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> data;
std::vector<std::string> temp;
unsigned line = 1;

while (std::cin >> input && input != "q") {
    temp.push_back(input);
    if (int(input) == line && line != 1) {
        data.push_back(temp);
        temp.clear();
        line++;
    }
}
```

This will fill up the `data` vector with all of the input from standard input that is not white-space until "q" is typed in.

Is that what you were looking for?

EDIT: I added your line by line (by line numbers) parsing request.

Comment: How does my program identify that `2   R 5001  E 4777` is not part of the module (from the second example)? Or that `1   z 2     1   xy 2` should be separated into line 1 and line 2 respectively?

Comment: `while(std::cin >> input && input != "q")` would be better... handles end-of-file (^Z on Windows keyboard,  ^D on UNIX/linux, or end of piped/redirected input).  MNRC: if the newlines are relevant, you can use `while (getline(std::cin, line)) { std::istringstream iss(line); ` then Paul's solution... `while (iss >> input && input != q) ...`, then after each line, do something with `data` - processing and removing the line, or storing some sentinel string to indicate that was where a line ended.

Comment: @TonyD You're right. I edited my answer. Yeah using isstringstream would be helpful if line by line parsing is what you want. The question is kind of confusing so it's hard to understand what you want ;) But yeah I agree with Tony

Comment: Hi Paul.  Looking at the question again, I noticed the "erroneous input"'s first line "2   R 5001  E 4777 1   z 2     1   xy 2" contains three "modules", and the remaining three-variable module is split across two lines, so my `getline()` suggestions wasn't very good - it wouldn't cope with that.  I've added an answer with my thoughts on a reasonable way to parse/store the data, if you're curious.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression:

```
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    // get data from file or user input etc. Here I have hardcoded it with
    // some newlines just to show how it works.
    std::string data =
        R"(2   R 5001  E 4777 1   z 2     1
        xy 2        3   A 8000
        E 1777        E 2001)";

    // Unfortunately the amount of space involved makes this regex rather
    // ugly, but basically "\s+" means to match at least one whitespace
    // character (which includes newlines, tabs, and spaces)
    std::regex moduleregex(R"(1\s+z\s+2\s+1\s+xy\s+2\s+3\s+([AMS])\s+(\d+)\s+E\s+(\d+)\s+E\s+(\d+))");

    std::smatch result;
    if (std::regex_search(data, result, moduleregex))
    {
        // Program will end up here if the match was successful
        std::string op = result[1];
        int operand1 = std::stoi(result[2]);
        int operand2 = std::stoi(result[3]);
        int operand3 = std::stoi(result[4]);

        // based on the input above:
        // "op" now contains "A" (it could be "M" or "S" depending on input)
        // "operand1" now contains 8000
        // "operand2" now contains 1777
        // "operand3" now contains 2001
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr << "Could not find module information in input" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Note that there is no error checking here except for whether or not the input matched the regular expression. You will want to wrap the code in a `try`/`catch` block and catch `std::out_of_range` which will be thrown if the input is too large for the `int` type (you can also use `long` with `std::stol` or `long long` with `std::stoll` if you need to support higher ranges). It will also only match positive numbers. If you want to match negative numbers, that's left as an exercise for the reader!

Answer (score 0):

This kind of thing is hard to do. Here is my :

```
ifstream in("file.txt");
vector<string> v;
string line;

while(getline(in, line)) {
    v.push_back(line.substr(1));   // remove line number
}
```

Comment: Hi G. Johal.  The `while(getline(` approach is so often useful, but on re-reading this question a few times, the user-typed input example's too broken to rely on line terminations for anything.  Your "line.substr(1));   // remove line number" also assumes the first number was meant to increment, but it seems to be the number of variable-name / numeric-value pairs that follow for that "module".

Comment: Additionally, if there are any blank lines in the input, this code invokes undefined behaviour.